# How can I efficiently store website URLs for web classification, where each website can have multiple class labels?

Tags: data-structures, multilabel-classification

I want to store a large number of websites, where each website can have multiple class labels. Ideally, I'd like to have a set of primary labels (entertainment, news, sports, etc.) for each website, and each of those primary labels can have a number of sub-classes (sports -> news and media -> ...). I want to be able to quickly access data by ether it's class or the website (or it's domain). What is the best data-structure to accomplish this?

Comment: Avoid "best", etc. in questions as such can often lead to subjectivity. In any case, this sounds like a 'simple' tree or BOM - what issues are there specifically?

Comment: How large is "a large number?" Do you want all this to fit into memory, or is disk storage sufficient? How quickly do you want to access it? How many queries per second are you expecting?